# How to convert a .csv file into a markdown outlined file?

Tags: r, dataframe, markdown

My data is contained in the following `csv` file, which has the following format:

```
ind h1 h2  x
1   a  aa  k 
2   a  ab  m 
3   b  ba  n 
4   b  bb  p
```

And I want to convert this into this `markdown` file:

```
# a
## aa
k
## ab
m
# b
## ba
n
## bb
p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `dt` is the dataframe from csv,

```
library(glue)
library(magrittr)
with(dt,{
  '\n#{h1}\n##{h2}\n{x}\n' %>% glue 
}) %>% writeLines(., con = 'out.md')
```